# actionscript web services event fires off to late

Tags: web-services, events, actionscript

I have a web service which is working find with the data proxy.
In this web service I have some functions I like to call and assign the results to a variable.

I found some example on this and below is what I have come up with.

Now all works but my event is being fired to late in the process. What I mean is once I call the getAdData() function and then call the webservice function getBleedAt() I need my event to fire off. what happening is the event is being fire at the end of the hold routine so I get my data to late.

I try using the dispatchEvent but can't get that to work.  the web service function is returning a XML structure

```
public function getAdddata(adnum:String){
        var WS:WebService = new WebService();
        WS.getBleedAt.addEventListener("result", GetInfo); 
        WS.getBleedAt.resultFormat = 'e4x'; 
        WS.loadWSDL(URL); 
        WS.getBleedAt(adnum);

    }

    private function GetInfo(evt:ResultEvent):void {

        var myObj:Object = evt.result as Object;
        trace(myObj.BleedAt.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to the web service returns asynchronously so your result handler (the GetInfo method) is the earliest point at which the result data is available to you. Therefore, any code which needs to access the result data needs to be triggered from the GetInfo method.

Comment: ok some redesign needs to happen here this is a good thanks very much.. I was looking into a custom event that I could some how trigger.. but I can rework this..

Comment: You may still want to fire a custom event (particularly if you need an instance of another class to react to the web service return), you just need to do it from the GetInfo method. It may even make sense to include the result of the web service call as a property of your custom event.

Comment: OK I look into this I have one I'm using and I can get it to fire off on demand this might work better for me thanks again